# How to embed a flow in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning-connect

I am developing a Lightning Component where i want to embed a visual flow, is it possible please guide me what is the syntax for it.

Comment: A flow? A workflow? a ui flow component? Can you elaborate a little bit?

Comment: Yes the ui flow component, the visual flow.

Answer (score 2):

Currently I think the only way you can achieve this is by embedding a VF page in your component and making use of the flow:interview component. Here are some details:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_flows_advanced.htm

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible in Winter '18 (v41).

Here's an example from the official documentation:

**example.cmp**

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
    <lightning:flow aura:id="flowData" />
</aura:component>
```

**exampleController.js**

```
({
    init : function (component) {
        var flow = component.find("flowData");
        flow.startFlow("myFlow");
    },
})
```

Apart from starting the flow, you can also pass input variables to it, retrieve output variables, and handle what happens at different stages of the flow (e.g. - you can now navigate to the created record when the flow finishes).

For complete documentation where you can see how to do all of this go to [this link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_distribute_internal_lc.htm).

Comment: I checked but didn't see a LWC equivalent. Is this only available in Aura at this time?

Answer (score 0):

Warning: This is unsupported and will probably break things either now or in the future!

Use window.location and specify the relative location of the flow url such as:

```
window.location = '/flow/[flowname]/?inputvariable1=unsupported&variable2=badidea'
```

Salesforce says this isn't supported and never to do it, but none of their supported methods such as `navigatetourl()` work. This method is unsupported because it can cause frame jumping and navigation issues, but has been used to pass javascript variables to a flow successfully on salesforce1 while maintaining the lightning experience skin for flows (which can't be done with their provided flow component since the input variables must be hard coded in the lightning app designer and visualforce embedding has its own problems including not supporting the lightning skin and not maintaining permissions for native phone functions such as gps coordinate requests).

Comment: You should NOT use window.location in lightning